# Is there any away to get absolute path of product image/featured image in Wordpress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i get absolute path of product Image or featured image of any post/product page?

I tried to like this:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $postid);
$product->get_image('large'); //output like <img src="url of image" alt="xyz"/>
```

Then i tried to get src path from image tag (from above output) using php prag_match function.
then split it by domain url and got remaining path and created absolute path.

```
$filename = getcwd().'/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/xyz.jpg';
```

It works for me but it seems complex and managed thing. Please let me know if there any easiest way?

Comment: The magic constant `__DIR__` contains the absolute path to the directory of the currently executing php script.

Comment: is there any other way to get absolute path of uploaded image for wordpress post?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use WP so I don't know. Have you looked into the WP documentation?

Comment: Yes but didn't find any good way to get absolute path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
echo esc_url( $feat_image );
```

- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-a-post-featured-image-url
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrieveing-featured-image-url
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/

To get the system path, Konstantin Kovshenin suggests the following:

```
$url       = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_ID );
$uploads   = wp_upload_dir();
$file_path = str_replace( $uploads['baseurl'], $uploads['basedir'], $url );
```

- https://kovshenin.com/2011/attachments-filename-and-directory-in-wordpress/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i need physical path of image it return url of image.

Comment: Sorry! Here's this should help: https://kovshenin.com/2011/attachments-filename-and-directory-in-wordpress/

Comment: `wp_upload_dir()` gives dir `/wp-content/uploads/2019/09`, so it changes each month...

Comment: @Gediminas It actually returns an array with several pieces of information, including `basedir` which is referenced in the answer above. `basedir` does not include the month subdirectories.